# Tail Recursion: Return Statement placement

Tags: c, recursion, return, tail-recursion

Though my program works the way I want it to, I was curious why I get a different result when I make a small change to get rid of a line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int i);
int main(void)
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter an integer greater than zero, (q to quit): ");
    while (scanf("%d",&num)==1)
    {
        //Checks if the entered integer is positive
        if (num<0)
            printf("Please enter a positive integer.\n");
        //Prints out the sum of the entered integer
        else
            printf("Sum(%d) = %d\n",num, sum(num));
        printf("Enter an integer greater than zero, (q to quit): ");
    }
    printf("Bye.");
    return 0;
}
//Calculates the sum of inputted value
int sum(int i)
{
    int answer;
    //Runs until the sum is added in reverse order
    if (i>0)
        answer=i+(sum(i-1));
    else
        answer=0;
    return answer;
}
```

In the function, I moved the "return answer;" to where "answer=0" is, and it produced a different result than I expected. Does anyone know why this is?
Inputting 1,4,5,and 7 produced a seemingly random number. Any other number from 1-10 produced the correct answer.
Thanks for any help!
Cheers,
Will.

Comment: You've asked 6 questions already, and received answers to most of them. Yet you didn't accept any answer on any of your questions. Were they *all* unhelpful?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! I'll fix that, sorry! Do you do that by clicking "Answer your question"? I thought that was for answering your own question. Is there something I am missing here? I thought there would be some sort of "Best answer" button like Yahoo! Answers has. Sorry I am new :(

Comment: There's a checkbox next to each answer. Under the vote arrows. It's how you accept. A nice way to show appreciation to the people that help, and to indicate this solved your problem, for future readers of your questions.

Comment: Scratch that, I am a fool. It's a simple checkmark by the upvote/downvote buttons! It was grayed out so I must have overlooked it.

Comment: BTW I think This isn't Tail Recursion.

Comment: @King Sutter  It is not clear how the function that gives different results looks.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY While you may be right, my textbook says that even though the recursion call isn't the last line of the function, it is the last statement executed when i>0.

Comment: Also, @StoryTeller I gave every question answer and will to this one, as well! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @KingSutter - It isn't. The addition is the last statement.

Comment: @KingSutter It's recursin call.  Read [Tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and StoryTeller 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I concur with **Iharob** that readability is the first consideration, there is still the matter of you trying to turn this function into tail recursion.

Now, if you simply do this:

```
int sum(int i)
{
    return i > 0 ? i + sum(i-1) : 0;
}
```

Then the function is a recursive one-liner with no undefined behavior, but it's not a tail recursion. It's not tail-recursive because the recursive function call is not the last operation in the function, that role goes to the addition. You don't just return the result of the recursive call.

Fortunately, it's quite easy to make this tail recursive:

```
int sum(int i, int n)
{
    return i > 0 ? sum(i - 1, i + n) : n;
}
```

By introducing a new variable that holds the sum, you can simply return the result of the recursive call.

---

If you must adhere to a single argument prototype, you can always make `sum` a wrapper for the real tail recursive function:

```
int sum_impl(int i, int n)
{
    return i > 0 ? sum_impl(i - 1, i + n) : n;
}

int sum(int i)
{
    return sum_impl(i, 0);
}
```

Comment: But then I have too few arguments where I call sum() in main. What do I do for int n?

Comment: @KingSutter - I was just updating my answer to touch upon that subject :)

Answer (score 3):

Because the function does not return otherwise and that's undefined behavior. Removing a line does not necessarily improve the code, don't do it just because it's less code, in fact I would write it like this

```
int
sum(int input)
{
    int answer;
    if (input > 0) {
        answer = input + (sum(input - 1));
    } else {
        answer = 0;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

More "*code*", but more readable too. I say "*code*" because they will both be compiled exactly the same, but this version is easier to be read.